# How to override parent in QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have an `ObjectTreeModel` class that inherits from `QAbstractItemModel`. The model stores `ObjectTreeItem` elements that have the `_placement` property, which is the `uuid` of another `ObjectTreeItem` element. I want that if an element has this property, then the `ObjectTreeModel::parent()` function returns the `placement` element, not the actual parent of the element and the tree structure changes accordingly. To do this, I redefined `parent()` in the `SortFilterProxyTreeModel` proxy model (inherited from QSortFilterProxyModel) of `ObjectTreeModel`, but as a result, the tree structure does not change. How can I redefine `parent()`correctly to get the desired result?

Source `ObjectTreeModel::parent()` function:

```cpp
QModelIndex ObjectTreeModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QModelIndex();

    ObjectTreeItem *childItem = getItem(index);
    ObjectTreeItem *parentItem = childItem ? childItem->parent() : nullptr;

    if (parentItem == rootItem || !parentItem)
        return QModelIndex();

    return createIndex(parentItem->childNumber(), 0, parentItem);
}
```

Overridden parent in `SortFilterProxyTreeModel`:

```cpp
QModelIndex SortFilterProxyTreeModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QModelIndex();
    
    // get original model
    ObjectTreeModel* treeModel = static_cast< ObjectTreeModel* >( sourceModel() );
    
    // convert the index from SortFilterProxyTreeModel to ObjectTreeModel
    QModelIndex sourceIndex = mapToSource( index );
    ObjectTreeItem *item = treeModel->getItem(sourceIndex);
    QModelIndex parentIndex;
    // if the uuid placement property exists, then we get its index, otherwise — the real parent.
    // the isPlacementParent variable is needed for optional behavior, by default it is true.
    const QUuid placementUuid = item->payload->_placement.value();
    if( isPlacementParent && !placementUuid.isNull() ) {
        ObjectTreeItem* placementItem = treeModel->items().value( placementUuid );
        parentIndex = treeModel->createThisIndex(placementItem->childNumber(), 0, placementItem);
        
    } else {
        ObjectTreeItem *parentItem = item ? item->parent() : nullptr;
        
        if (parentItem == treeModel->rootItem || !parentItem)
            return QModelIndex();
        
        parentIndex = treeModel->createThisIndex(parentItem->childNumber(), 0, parentItem);
    }
    // convert parentIndex from ObjectTreeModel to SortFilterProxyTreeModel
    return mapFromSource( parentIndex );
}
```

Comment: First, you will definitely have to change your `SortFilterProxyModel` for some subclass of `QIdentityProxyModel`, that will remove 1 level of complexity for you and for the people who will try to answer your question. If you need to keep to have sort/filter functionality, then just set that as the source model of a normal `QSortFilterProxyModel` (= `ObjectTreeModel` being the source of a `ReorganizedObjectProxyModel` which in turns is the source of a `QSortFilterProxyModel`)

Comment: Then you have to override `mapFromSource`/`mapToSource` (the other methods just call those 2 -> do **NOT** override `index` nor `parent`) and everything related to the rows under a parent index: `hasChildren`, `rowCount`, `insertRows`, `moveRows`, `removeRows`. I think you will run into a problem exactly here though. While I see how you find the `placement` element of any `ObjectTreeItem`, I did not see in your question how you do the opposite, that is find all the `ObjectTreeItem` that have the same `placement`. People will not be able to answer you if you do not explain this part.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'll try to redefine these methods additionally and then say what happened.